# ofstream/fstream simply will not work, no matter what solution is tried

Tags: c++, fstream, flush, fclose

Okay guys, I've tried everything I can think of. I'm passing in a file name into this function. A little context: hash_table is an already initialized and filled vector with key pairs, and the 'value' part of the pair is a Linked List that has the field "bucket_size". When I use cout to check if these fields are actually being accessed, they are; even the debugger lists them as being filed into the output stream. I have flush() and close() in there, but it doesn't write anything to the file. Returns true, indicating no errors in the stream. Anyone have nay ideas?

```
 string line;
 std::ofstream ofs;
 if(ofs.is_open())
     ofs.close();
 ofs.open(filename);
 if (ofs.is_open())
 {
     cout << "File Opened" << endl;
     for (double i = 0; i < hash_table.capacity(); ++i)
     {
         ofs << "Bucket Number " << i;
         if (hash_table[i].value != NULL)
             ofs << " Bucket Size: " << hash_table[i].value->bucket_size << endl;
         else
             ofs << " Bucket Size: 0" << endl;
         ofs.flush();
     }
     cout << "closing file stream" << endl;
     ofs.flush();
 ofs.close();
 if (ofs.good())
         return true;
     else
         return false;
 }
 else
 {
 cout << "File not opened" << endl;
 return false;
 }
```

}

Comment: Why exactly are you checking `ofs.is_open()` after instantiating `ofs`?

Comment: if any file is associated with the stream, per this article: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/is_open/

Comment: What @caspase means is no file could possibly be associated with the stream when you do the first `ofs.is_open()`. Line 3 is pointless and line 4 will never be executed.

Comment: But why exactly should a file be opened, right after you instantiate `ofs` (I'm talking about the first `is_open()`, not the second one); also, why in the hell are you using a `double` for `i`? Also, have you checked the return value of `hash_table.capacity()`??

Comment: So are you saying that if you replace the writes to `ofs` with `cout` you get correct output? But if `ofs` refers to a file on disk it ends up empty?

Comment: You should use a debugger rather than the ancient art of print statements.

Comment: Use `hash_table.size()` not `hash_table.capacity()`.

Comment: filename is previously declared via a passed in parameter. I read that you can check to see if a stream is attached to some previous file through the is_open() function, and then close it, so that I can reopened a new one to be associated with the filename I'm passing. 

@caspase I changed the declaration of i to    typeof(hash_table.capacity()) i = 0; 

Same result, no writes. I added a cout << hash_table[i].value->bucket_size to the first if condition and puts brackets around it, it outputs the correct output to the screen so the table is working

0x499602D2 I'm looking for empty entries to

Comment: @Carey Correct. Cout works, ofstream does not.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I agree, and I am, and the output stream summary actually lists itself as containing all of the information I want it to contain. It just won't write to the file. The file is closed, not open anywhere else or anything, and there's only one; I'm not getting confused as to which file it's writing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost certainly examining the wrong file. Remember that relative paths are relative to the working directory of the process, which is not necessarily the same as where the executable lives on disk.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled and ran it by the console and now it works, with no edits made. It seems my IDE doesn't like something in the code. Regardless, thank you everyone for the response.s

Comment: Then you should delete the question since it will never be of use to anyone else.